# How do I edit Comments.php so I can add Schema markup to comment output?

Tags: comments

I can only find posts to edit the input and related fields.

How do I structure my edits to include proper schema markup? (I have written out what that should be)

Answer (score 0):

The comments are outputted via a callback function given as an argument in this function: `wp_list_comments()`.

In your comments.php you will likely find the `wp_list_comments()` function with often a callback argument like so
`wp_list_comments( array ( 'callback' => 'callback_function_name'))`

You can copy comments.php into your child-theme and modify the call to the function with a different callback function like so:
`wp_list_comments( array ( 'callback' => 'my_comments_html'))`

Then find the function from your original callback parameter `'callback_function_name'`, copy it in your child theme (in functions.php or make another .php file and include it), rename the function to `'my_comments_html'` and modify it there with the markup you like.

Hope that helps